# CaslteWindsor LifestyleScoped uses the SAME instance between requests

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Project is ASP.NET using CastleWindsor for IoC

I have registered the class that inherits DBContext like this

```
IoCcontainer.Register(Component.For<IMyContext>().ImplementedBy<MYContext>().LifestyleScoped())
```

I do this in Startup.cs (of ASP.net). In the method: ConfigureServices
I also call

```
IoCcontainer.BeginScope();
```

in that same method.

But When I run the app and call different pages or the same page twice, I get the same instance of MyContext.
I know this because in DbContect.[entity].Local; I have the previous requests entity instances and I ought no have any.

So where should I call

```
IoCcontainer.BeginScope();
```

To reduce the scope to a single request?

I have tried using the Core DI's

```
services.AddScoped<IMyContext, MyContext>()
```

But I get a different instance of MyContext for each Dao class instanceses in the same request.

Wouldn't mind knowing how configure the Core so the same instance is used for all Dao class instanceses

Answer (score 0):

Solved DBContext Multi instances issue
 ie parameterless constructor required on dbContext class